# Vagrant Vhost with a FQDN (Full Qualified Domain Name)

Tags: vagrant, vhosts

Take a domain name like:
**development.mysite.com**

I want to setup a vhost with Vagrant that would allow me to access this location in my browser.

From what I can tell, it won't let me use port 80, so even if I change my hosts file to something like:

```
127.0.0.1 development.mysite.com
```

It still won't find it.

Does anyone have an idea?

---

**UPDATE**

**VagrantFile**

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# Vagrantfile API/syntax version. Don't touch unless you know what you're doing!
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  # Every Vagrant virtual environment requires a box to build off of.
  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise32"

  # Networking
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8000
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"

  # Synced folders
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www"

  # Provisioning
  config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "apt-get update --fix-missing"

  config.vm.provision :shell do |shell|
    shell.inline = "mkdir -p /etc/puppet/modules;
                    (puppet module install example42/puppi; true)
                    (puppet module install example42/apache; true)
                    (puppet module install example42/php; true)
                    (puppet module install puppetlabs/stdlib; true)
                    (puppet module install puppetlabs/mysql; true)
                    (puppet module install saz/vim; true)"
  end

  config.vm.provision "puppet" do |puppet|
    puppet.facter = {
      "fqdn" => "development.eatologie.com",
      "hostname" => "www",
      "docroot" => '/var/www/html/'
    }
    puppet.manifests_path = "puppet"
    puppet.manifest_file  = "site.pp"
  end
end
```

**Puppet site.pp**

```
###########################
# Eatologie Puppet Config #
###########################
# OS          : Linux     #
# Database    : MySQL 5   #
# Web Server  : Apache 2  #
# PHP version : 5.4       #
###########################

# Vim
class { 'vim': }

# Puppi
class { 'puppi': }

# Apache setup
class { "apache":
    puppi        => true,
    puppi_helper => "myhelper",
}

apache::vhost { $fqdn :
    docroot => $docroot,
    server_name => $fqdn,
    priority            => '',
    template            => 'apache/virtualhost/vhost.conf.erb',
}

apache::module { 'rewrite': }

# PHP Extensions
class {"php":}

php::module { ['xdebug', 'mysql', 'curl', 'gd']:
    notify => Service['apache2']
}

# MySQL Server
class { '::mysql::server':
  root_password    => 'abc123',
}

mysql::db { 'eatdb':
    user     => 'admin',
    password => 'abc456',
    host     => 'localhost',
    grant    => ['all'],
    charset => 'utf8',
}

# Eatologie Setup

file { $docroot:
    ensure  => 'directory',
}

$writeable_dirs = ["${docroot}cache/", "${docroot}cache/css/", "${docroot}cache/css/js/"]

file { $writeable_dirs:
    ensure => "directory",
    mode   => '0777',
    require => File[$docroot],
}
```

Comment: Are you running any caching mechanism (e.g. Varnish) on your vagrant setup? And can you include your vagrantfile?

Comment: @MF82 Added, no varnish or other caching unless it came default in the box (I doubt it)

Comment: And to whomever, why the negative vote?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can see, this is the relevant part in your Vagrantfile:

```
# Networking
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8000
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
```

It means that your Vagrantbox is accessible at ip 192.168.33.10 and port 8000. So, your hosts file should say

```
192.168.33.10   development.eatologie.com
```

instead of

```
127.0.0.1   development.mysite.com
```

With that change, you should be to access your site at `development.eatologie.com:8000`

For more info, also take a look at the Vagrant documentation pages for [forwarded ports](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/forwarded_ports.html) and [private networking](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/private_network.html). For the private networking part take into account that, if you assign a static IP to your Vagrant box (as you did in your setup), you have to be sure the IP is not taken by another device on your local network.

Comment: Okay, so I got it working at development.eatologie.com:8000, but I don't want to have to specify a port, just the FQDN, I can't seem to find a way to do that.

Comment: Try commenting out the forwarded_port line and do a `vagrant reload`. Are you then able to access your site by FQDN only? I checked my own vagrantfile, but I have no forwarded_port defined...

Comment: Didn't work, what version of vagrant? I am running 1.6.3

Comment: Also 1.6.3. Can you also post your vhost template? (apache/virtualhost/vhost.conf.erb). Perhaps the VHost is listening on another port...

Comment: I found the answer -- it isn't possible with vagrant with these ports. https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/forwarded_ports.html - the ports must be over 1024, so there is no way to make it listen on port 80. I found that if I use something like Fiddler2 I can make it work, otherwise I just have to deal with the port number.